# Did a git cherry-pick of change that was already present, how can I revert back to previous state

Tags: git

By mistake I did a git cherry-pick of a change that was already present in the current branch.

Now whenever I run "git status" it shows me the following:

```
# On branch master
# You are currently cherry-picking.
#   (all conflicts fixed: run "git commit")
```

How can I revert back to previous state so that the above message is not shown in git status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
git cherry-pick --abort
```